# Retrieve ABI file using a ERC721's contract address

Tags: solidity, erc-721

Is there a way to to retrieve a ERC721 contract's ABI programmatically using its `contractAddress`?

Not sure how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Etherscan API allows you to retrieve ABIs for **verified** contracts. They have documentation for [this exact usecase](https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/contracts), but I don't know of any reliable way to retrieve ABIs for unverified ones.